# Find all local minima in an N-dimensional array in MATLAB/Octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, minimum

I would like to find general code to find all local minima in an N-dimensional array in MATLAB or Octave.

For a 2D array, a rough idea would be

```
localmin = [];
for i=2:N-1
    for j=2:N-1
        if M(i,j)<=M(i,j+1) && M(i,j)<=M(i,j-1) && M(i,j)<=M(i+1,j) && M(i,j)<=M(i-1,j)
            localmin = [localmin,[i;j]];
        end
    end
end
```

(The ends of the array would need to be addressed with different conditions, of course, but for simplicity of the example I ignored that.)

Is there a way way to make a single function that handles arbitrary dimensions? I'm sure there is one, since a number of built-in functions for dealing with arrays handle arbitrary dimensions, but I do not know how to handle this.

Comment: If finding the regional minima is enough, there is [`imregionalmin`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/imregionalmin.html) on the image package. It works with an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: Do you know the bounds for each dimension in the domain?

Comment: carandraug, thank you! I had not been aware of that.
SecretAgentMan, the dimension would be variable. Why would I need to know it ahead of time? I could always find it with size().

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`islocalmax`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islocalmax.html) or [`islocalmin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islocalmin.html) (`imregionalmax` is part of the image processing toolbox in Matlab, so I guess not available to everyone). These functions will find local minima in an n-dimensional array, along a certain dimension, and return the a boolean array with 1's at the locations of these local max or mins.

By applying this function in multiple directions on your data, and finding the intersection of these boolean arrays (simply `&`, element wise `and`), you can find the location of your local peaks.

```
% generate some data
x = -10:0.1:10;
y = -10:0.1:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y); 
Z = cos(X).*sin(Y).*(X+Y);

% determine maxima and minima
% For Matlab without image processing toolbox:
isMax = islocalmax(Z,1) & islocalmax(Z,2); % combine maxima along first dim with second dim
isMin = islocalmin(Z,1) & islocalmin(Z,2);
% Octave with image package and Matlab with image processing toolbox:
isMax = imregionalmax(Z);
isMin = imregionalmin(Z);

% plot
figure(1);clf;
surf(X,Y,Z);
hold on
scatter3(X(isMax), Y(isMax), Z(isMax), 'r', 'filled')
scatter3(X(isMin), Y(isMin), Z(isMin), 'b', 'filled')
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work for the N-d case, but I don't have a good example to check that right now.

Comment: might be worth pointing out regardless that the `isMax = imregionalmax(Z)` approach would make it compatible with octave too (using the 'image' package)

Comment: rinkert, ironically, islocalmin has not been adapted to Octave but imregionalmin has. I'll just use imregionalmin. Thank you nonetheless!